# get notification key error 401 gcm https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/googlenotification

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

im trying to get notification key from google service im following the documentation from http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html and im Generating  a Notification Key on the Client but im having a problem with the post request getting error 401 OK

```
{
   "operation": "create",
   "notification_key_name": "vitee",
   "registration_ids": ["********"]
   "id_token": "**************************************************"
}
```

here is a snapshot of my request

![enter image description here][1]

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/QmTDFWwjkyPtLFVVcTN4IYwkVhHU42wcUKPjpg_E8KSR3ALAXJ2Js-0K2gzlmmOEUXfrGe1TS8s=w1890-h820

Comment: Also make sure that you have activated the GCM API in the Developers Console.

Comment: I've got the same error, have you solved in someway? I'm trying to get the notification key in the client as well.

Comment: Looks like notification_key_name needs to be the email of the user that gets your id_token, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34298106/3983628).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) with local device groups on Android gives HTTP Error code 401](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098773/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-with-local-device-groups-on-android-gives-http-erro)

Answer (score 0):

Your header for `projectid` is mislabeled and is using the project number instead of the API key as the value.

So,

1. change `project_id` to `Authorization` as the name
2. and as the value `key=YOUR_PROJECT_API_KEY` which may be found on the Credentials page:

Here's some help to find your api key via the Credentials page:

1. https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0
2. Click the project you want (in case you have more than one)
3. Click **API & auth** (if it isn't expanded already)
4. Click Credentials (underneath **API & auth**)
5. And then you will find your API key on this screen

Comment: i changed the project_id to authorization and i entered MY_PROJECT_API_KEY as the value but I amgetting an error 400 OK.    According to your statement you are trying to generate a notification key on the server however, i am trying to generate a Notification Key on the Client. Check this out - http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a user notification on your client, you cannot use the "create" operation. Use "add" instead. As mentioned in the documentation, "add" creates the notification key if it doesn't exist.

In generating the `id_token`, make sure that you specify the client ID (not API key) in your `scope` object.

Comment: we got the id_token however when we pass it into

Comment: we got the id_token however when we pass it into JSON format to make a call to google server                                                               {"operation": "add",
   "notification_key_name":"a",                                                                       "registration_ids":["**"]                                                                                            "id_token":"*" }                                                                                                                       I dont receive the notification key and I get an error of 401 OK